# API to change/edit Windows "host" or "lmhost" files

Tags: .net, winapi

I was wondering if there is a .Net or even a native API that would allow us to edit the Windows host file. The reasons for preferring an API to raw access would be not having to deal with multiple locations for the file and validation, of course.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would there be multiple locations for the file?

Comment: Its location is fixed relative to the windows dir;  `Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, @"drivers\etc\hosts");`

Comment: These files were always supposed to be edited by an administrator using a text editor.  This goes back to the early days of Unix.  There is no api for it.

Comment: @AlexK., true, but it has been so since Windows 2000 (I think). There are no guarantees that it won't change in the future. But thanks for the snippet! :)

Comment: Hey @HansPassant! I get that it's supposed to be edited by hand, but I'd like to make an application that changes it. I guess I was with something like the crontab in my mind: you can change it by hand, but there's a program that facilitates access to it.